# How do I awk a unix text file to a predefined html code?

Tags: html, unix, awk

I don't know HTML (HORRIBLY EMBARRASSED but didn't ever have the need to).  I am pretty perspicacious when it comes to UNIX however I am horribly confused with this assignment I have.  I know what I need to do but am having the hardest time ever getting started.

I have the following files in my hwk12 directory:

- roster.html
- roster.txt
- sample.html
- sample.txt

The following is the content of the roster.html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border=2>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nikhil Banerjee</td>
    <td>nbanerje</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:zetapsi796@hotmail.com">zetapsi796@hotmail.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jeff Nazarian</td>
    <td>jnazaria</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:jeff.nazarian@asu.edu">jeff.nazarian@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anna Melzer</td>
    <td>amelzer</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:anna.melzer@asu.edu">anna.melzer@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jose Garcia</td>
    <td>jgarcia</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:garcia-j@msn.com">garcia-j@msn.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jillian Testa</td>
    <td>jtesta</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:jillian.testa@asu.edu">jillian.testa@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Clayton Lengelzigich</td>
    <td>clengelz</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:clayton.lengel-zigich@asu.edu">clayton.lengel-  
zigich@asu.edu</a></td>               
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ashley Bennett</td>
    <td>abennett</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:ashley.bennett@asu.edu">ashley.bennett@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ann Frost</td>
    <td>afrost</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:ann.frost@asu.edu">ann.frost@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Timothy Whipple</td>
    <td>twhipple</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:tweed@asu.edu">tweed@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wei Shen</td>
    <td>wshen</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:shenwei58@hotmail.com">shenwei58@hotmail.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cari Mahon</td>
    <td>cmahon</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:cari.mahon@asu.edu">cari.mahon@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alberto Salas</td>
    <td>asalas</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:alberto2504@msn.com">alberto2504@msn.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dorothy Haskett</td>
    <td>dhaskett</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:dorothy.haskett@asu.edu">dorothy.haskett@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Criss Bradbury</td>
    <td>cbradbur</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:crissbradbury@hotmaiil.com">crissbradbury@hotmaiil.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Steve Ellermann</td>
    <td>sellerma</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:cis494@ellermann.com">cis494@ellermann.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zewdie Bekele</td>
    <td>zbekele</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:zewdiea@aol.com">zewdiea@aol.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Frederic Diziere</td>
    <td>fdiziere</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:fsd@asu.edu">fsd@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Matt Bowes</td>
    <td>mbowes</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:matt.bowes@asu.edu">matt.bowes@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jasen Meece</td>
    <td>jmeece</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:jasen.meece@sun.com">jasen.meece@sun.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Aaron Carpenter</td>
    <td>acarpent</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:aaron.carpenter@asu.edu">aaron.carpenter@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Binqin Xi</td>
    <td>bxi</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:binqin.xi@asu.edu">binqin.xi@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yinting Chan</td>
    <td>ychan</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:yin.chen@asu.edu">yin.chen@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Michael Evans</td>
    <td>mevans</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:michael.evans@asu.edu">michael.evans@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Herman Beringer</td>
    <td>hberinge</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:jber@cox.net">jber@cox.net</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Andrew Jolley</td>
    <td>ajolley</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:andrew@andrewjolley.com">andrew@andrewjolley.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Michael Raby</td>
    <td>mraby</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:mike1071@yahoo.com">mike1071@yahoo.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hajar Alaoui</td>
    <td>halaoui</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:hajar6@hotmail.com">hajar6@hotmail.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anne Lemar</td>
    <td>alemar</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:anne.lemar@asu.edu">anne.lemar@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Russell Crotts</td>
    <td>rcrotts</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:Russell.Crotts@asu.edu">Russell.Crotts@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dan Mazzola</td>
    <td>dmazzola</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:dan.mazzola@sun.com">dan.mazzola@sun.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Boyton</td>
    <td>bboyton</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:boytonb@earthlink.net">boytonb@earthlink.net</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is the content of the roster.txt file:

```
Whipple Timothy tweed@asu.edu Shen    Wei     shenwei58@hotmail.com
Mahon   Cari    cari.mahon@asu.edu Salas   Alberto alberto2504@msn.com
Haskett Dorothy dorothy.haskett@asu.edu Bradbury        Criss  
crissbradbury@hotmaiil.com Ellermann       Steve  
cis494@ellermann.com Bekele  Zewdie  zewdiea@aol.com Diziere Frederic 
fsd@asu.edu Bowes   Matt    matt.bowes@asu.edu Meece   Jasen  
jasen.meece@sun.com  Carpenter       Aaron   aaron.carpenter@asu.edu
Xi      Binqin  binqin.xi@asu.edu Chan    Yinting yin.chen@asu.edu
Evans   Michael michael.evans@asu.edu Beringer        Herman 
jber@cox.net Jolley  Andrew  andrew@andrewjolley.com Raby    Michael
mike1071@yahoo.com Alaoui  Hajar   hajar6@hotmail.com Lemar   Anne   
anne.lemar@asu.edu Crotts  Russell Russell.Crotts@asu.edu Mazzola Dan 
dan.mazzola@sun.com Boyton  Bill    boytonb@earthlink.net
```

The following is the content of the sample.html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border=2>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Michael Raby</td>
    <td>mraby</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:mike1071@yahoo.com">mike1071@yahoo.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hajar Alaoui</td>
    <td>halaoui</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:hajar6@hotmail.com">hajar6@hotmail.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anne Lemar</td>
    <td>alemar</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:anne.lemar@asu.edu">anne.lemar@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Russell Crotts</td>
    <td>rcrotts</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:Russell.Crotts@asu.edu">Russell.Crotts@asu.edu</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dan Mazzola</td>
    <td>dmazzola</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:dan.mazzola@sun.com">dan.mazzola@sun.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Boyton</td>
    <td>bboyton</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:boytonb@earthlink.net">boytonb@earthlink.net</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is the content of the sample.txt file:

```
Raby    Michael mike1071@yahoo.com
Alaoui  Hajar   hajar6@hotmail.com
Lemar   Anne    anne.lemar@asu.edu
Crotts  Russell Russell.Crotts@asu.edu
Mazzola Dan     dan.mazzola@sun.com
Boyton  Bill    boytonb@earthlink.net
```

I'm not asking for someone to do this for me because I LOVE UNIX and I want to learn it myself.  Everytime I look at this HTML code I am confusing the #$$#& out of myself.  I need help getting started.

The homework prompt is the following:

You are to write a nawk(1) script called ~/hwk12/mk_html.awk that converts a text file (sample.txt and roster.txt) to an html page that a web browser can read. I have given you the output in the file sample.html which is reproduced below (notice how each level of indentation is two spaces deep):

Again, I don't want someone to do this for me.  Im just confused as to how data in the text file will append to the HTML table without the actual HTML code.  Can someone please help me get started?

Comment: Is that really how the input file is formatted? random line breaks throughout, instead of a nice `email fname lname`-per line?

Comment: Im pretty sure I need to loop through the text file and awk the appropriate columns to the html code.  Am I right in saying this?

Comment: @MarcB are you speaking of the roster.txt file?

Comment: @MarcB, I don't know why it got reformatted when I posted the question.  There is only on name with their relevant info per row, There is know random line breaks however some names in the file are not equally spaced

Comment: I guess this is my main question:  Do I append the relevant data from the text file to the html file where they need to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to define the necessary HTML tags within your script. The meat of the html file will be these lines:

```
<tr>
    <td>$first $last</td>
    <td>$username</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:$email">$email</a></td>
</tr>
```

These tags define a table row. You can parse the variables from the text files with awk and use them to fill in the html. The other html markup can be copy-pasted as static text into the output html file.

Edit: You can do this to grab the first and last name and print to the html file.

```
last = $1
first = $2
print "  <tr>"
print "    <td>" first " " last "</td>"
print "  </tr>"
```

You just need to expand that to get the email and username.

Comment: This is an awk assignment, can I do this with awk?

Comment: I don't know HTML and my professor said you don't need to know it.  Am I correct in saying the following?:  I need to create a loop that will awk the columns and append them to the HTML file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant awk, I don't know why I said sed. Edited the above. And you don't need to know html, you just need to use that format.

Comment: Would I use a for loop since I know the amount of columns I need to append? Im confused about the condition I would set it to

Comment: No, you don't need a for loop. You can reference the columns in your .txt file by calling '$' + (column number). For example, $1 would give you the last name in each column.

Comment: You don't need conditions either, since every line is the same format and you're doing the exact same thing. Giving you a bit of code to give you an idea of what the solution should look like.

Comment: Thank you, you have been helpful.  That little code will help me get started.  I cant upvote you because I don't have 15 reputation yet.  However, I accepted your answer.

Comment: I upvoted you.  Im assuming you upvoted me say I can have this priveledge. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, in an default pattern block (leave the condition blank). You can put the header and footer html in BEGIN and END blocks.

Comment: You've been very helpful.  I know what I need to do now.  I was thinking about this WAYYYY to hard.  One last question, can I write a statement within the nawk script where $2 is so that I can grab just the first letter from the first name and put it in front of the last name to make the username?

Comment: You should look up concatenation and substrings in awk.